# TypeError , no puedo mapear json a modelo . Angular 4

Tags: typescript, angular

estoy haciendo un formulario para crear una cuenta y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Lo primero que hago es ir a buscar el json a una api que por el momento tengo el json de manera local en assets,

Este es el metodo del servicio que se encarga de buscar el json

```
getJoinCustomer():Observable<JoinCustomer>{
  return this.http
        .get(this._url).pipe(
          map((res:Response)=>res.json())
        )
}
```

Luego en mi componente inyecto el servicio y lo llamo dentro de un metodo para mapearlo a mi propiedad.

```
  getJoinCustomer():void{
    this._joinService.getJoinCustomer()
    .subscribe(joinCustomer => {
          this.joinCustomer = joinCustomer;
                     this.join = new Join(this.joinCustomer.customerID)                              
          })
```

Y llamo este metodo desde el

```
ngOnInit(){
this.getJoinCustomer();
}
```

E inclusive si hiciera el modelo de la siguiente forma

```
    {"joinCustomer":[{
   "customerID":"ASD123"
   }]}
```

JSON

```
    export class JoinCustomer{
   customerID:string;
   }
```

JoinCustomer.ts

Me genera el error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerID' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto te ocurre porque en la función:

```
  getJoinCustomer():void{
    this._joinService.getJoinCustomer()
    .subscribe(joinCustomer => this.joinCustomer = joinCustomer)

    console.log(this.joinCustomer.customerID) //this is TypeError
  }
```

usas la propiedad joinCustomer fuera del subscribe por lo que seguramente en este momento sea undefined, ya que es una llamada asíncrona y puede tardar X tiempo en saltar el subscribe.

Si quieres mostrar por consola que te trae el dato correctamente, sería así:

```
  getJoinCustomer():void{
    this._joinService.getJoinCustomer()
    .subscribe(joinCustomer => {

         this.joinCustomer = joinCustomer
         console.log(this.joinCustomer.customerID) //this is TypeError
    })


  }
```

Comment: mmm me sigue apareciendo como undefined, puse el console.log ahi para ver si traia el dato nada mas la idea es llamarlo despues de llamar el metodo en el ngOninit y ahi es donde me tira undefined realmente

Comment: Edito lo siento en el console lo he puesto antes de asignarlo xD

Comment: Si, el tema es que llamando todo dentro del subscribe funciona, pero tendría que ser asi?

Comment: Tiene que ser así y eso es porque haces un petición get que es asíncrona , por lo tanto no sabes cuando vas a recibir la respuesta y el subscribe se mantiene a la espera de la respuesta, y cuando llega salta y se ejecuta por eso tiene que estar dentro. Qué problema se te presenta que este dentro?

Comment: ahi edite , yo inicializo el join dentro del subscribe porque dentro forma mi joincustomer es undefined, despues si tengo que hacer un submit por ejemplo con ese join, va a estar disponible?

Comment: Te explico, la variable join va a dejar de ser undefined en el momento que la petición get de una respuesta. Ahora si tu petición get tarda 10 seg ( tiempo exagerado) y das submit al segundo pues seguira siendo undefined, ya que no ha dado tiempo a procesar la petición get, pero una vez que la petición de una respuesta la variable join tendrá el valor asignado.

Answer (score 0):

{"joinCustomer":**[**{
   "customerID":"ASD123"
   }**]**}

la razon por la cual sale el error es por que no puedes acceder a un elemento que esta dentro un array o lista de esa manera, seria por ejm asi:
**this.joinCustomer[0].customerID**

Comment: si de igual manera cambio el json, sigue sin andar afuera del subscribe, como que no termina de cargar el dato antes de que haga el render del componente